# csv to java transformation through smooks

Tags: java, smooks

I have csv file which is needed to be converted into java file by creating object .
I did this through the example csv to java given in smooks 1.5 and it is running properly.
But if I use a new csv sheet then i need to change the field name every where.
Can any one help me if there is a process to convert csv to java through position wise so that i dont need to change field name everytime.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you are still looking for a framework, check out BeanIO at http://www.beanio.org

Also look into http://camel.apache.org/beanio.html